# "Recall that the bundle of $s$-densities on a Riemannian manifold has a natural connection, which preserves the canonical section"

Tags: riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles

From the book "[Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540200628)" (Getzler et al):

> Recall that the bundle $|\Lambda|^s$ of $s$-densities on a Riemannian manifold has a natural connection, which preserves the canonical section $|dx|^s$

Unfortunately Getzler does not provide any reference and I don't even know what "preserves" means in this context. Can someone please elaborate?

Comment: "Preserves" is a shortcut for saying that the covariant derivative of this density is a zero section. For the definitions, look up pages 30, 34 and 68 (for "canonical" density). By the way, in the book, they specify the section: $|dx|^s$.

Comment: @YuriVyatkin Thank you for the comment. In fact this already defines the covariant derivative, right? Because a section of $|\Lambda|^s$ is always of the form $uv$, where $u$ is a real-valued function and $v$ is the canonical section and by the definition of covariant derivatives (definition 1.14) we have $$\nabla(uv)=(\mathrm{d}u)v+u(\nabla v)=(\mathrm{d}u)v+0=(\mathrm{d}u)v.$$So all we have to do is to show that this function is indeed a covariant derivative and then we have proven Getzler's claim. Do you agree?

Comment: I agree. You can define the connection this way and check that it has the required properties. I would write it as $ \nabla (\alpha |\mathrm{d} x|^s ) := (\mathrm{d} \alpha) |\mathrm{d} x|^s $, where $\alpha |\mathrm{d} x|^s$ is a generic form of a section in the bundle of $s$-densities.